# How to add superuser in Django from fixture

Tags: django, django-fixtures

How to add SUPERuser(not just user) through Django fixtures?

Let's say I wanna have login:admin, password:admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Users in initial data fixture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017204/users-in-initial-data-fixture)

Comment: This is on page 2 of the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/)...

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup I'm talking about superuser, not usual user.

Comment: @Sayse I'm looking for solution, which uses fixtures, not manual input

Comment: @GriMel A superuser is a normal user with the `is_superuser` flag set.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## solution 1

On empty database:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
python manage.py dumpdata auth.User --indent 4 > users.json
```

and in `users.json` You have needed fixtures.

## solution 2

```
./manage.py shell

>>> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
>>> make_password('test')
'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$vkRy7QauoLLj$ry+3xm3YX+YrSXbri8s3EcXDIrx5ceM+xQjtpLdw2oE='
```

and create fixtures file:

```
[
    { "model": "auth.user",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$10000$vkRy7QauoLLj$ry+3xm3YX+YrSXbri8s3EcXDIrx5ceM+xQjtpLdw2oE="
            "is_superuser": true,
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_active": true
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: This is what i've been looking for. Why did I get minuses?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can use the existing fixture [admin_user](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#admin-user-an-admin-user-superuser).

From RTD:

> An instance of a superuser, with username “admin” and password “password” (in case there is no “admin” user yet).